# how to change align of combobox item to right?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I create a `combobox` in `WPF` (.net 4.5.1) by following `xaml code`, how to changed `alignment` of `items` to `right` like image?

```
 <ComboBox
    x:Name="cmbPost"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="0"
    TabIndex="6"
    Width="150"
    Margin="5"
    Height="22"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add `HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"` to your combobox